# How to always set focus to a button even click on some other textbox or other controls?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need behavior like in the excel Find and Replace dialogBox that's why i asked like this. In this image you can able to see FindNext is always focused

[image: FindNext is always focused]

I could able to set the focus to single element that is either Textbox or Button. But my requirement is always i need to set focus to Button even i click the some other controls within the window.

Comment: You need to reset button focus every time when you change your focus on something.

Comment: May I ask why? Is it just because you want a user to be able to press Enter/Return at all times to invoke the button?

Comment: Second @Rowbear, there is other way to achieve that (by setting Button's `IsDefault="True"` ). And for the approach you are considering, if you keep prevent user from setting focus to other controls (e.g. textbox), how can they input anything?

Comment: I have attached an screenshot in this query please find it and share your opinion.

Answer (score 2):

As I said in the comment, just set `IsDefault="True"` for your button will give you the result you want in the images you posted.

e.g.

```
<Button Content="Button" IsDefault="True" />
```

Result:

You can see the button will be highlighted even when user input into the textbox.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to do this. But you can always set up a `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` on the Window, and check the `e.OriginalSource` property to see if it is a Control you want to give focus to. If it is not something you want to give focus to, simply set `e.Handled` to `true`.

But, seriously, it is still weird why you want to do this.

#### Edited because of your edited question

The "Find Next" button only visually looks focused. The focus is still given to the search `TextBox` or the replace `TextBox`. When you hit "Enter", the `TextBox` handles that `KeyEvent`, and executes the same `Command` as the "Find Next" button.

If you want to do something like that, you probably can consider this:

- Add a property (probably `bool ShouldButtonLookFocused`) somewhere
- Set up a Data Trigger in the button that binds to this `ShouldButtonLookFocused` property), set trigger value to true (e.g. `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ShouldButtonLookFocused}" Value="True">`
- Set the data trigger's setter to whatever visual changes you want to indicate this.
- Then add bindings to which ever other `TextBox` controls, which when focused, you would want the button to "look focused". The binding should be to this `ShouldButtonLookFocused` property, and most likely you need to use a `Converter` for this.

Example:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ShouldButtonLookFocused}" Value="True">
      <!-- Whatever visual thing you can think of -->
      <Setter Property="Border" Value="Red" />
    </DataTrigger>  
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>


public static readonly DependencyProperty ShouldButtonLookFocusedProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ShouldButtonLookFocused",
    typeof(bool),
    typeof(WhicheverClassThisIsIn));

public bool ShouldButtonLookFocused
{
    get
    {
        return (bool)GetValue(ShouldButtonLookFocusedProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue(ShouldButtonLookFocusedProperty, value);
    }
}


<TextBox Name="SearchBox"
    IsFocused="{Binding Path=ShouldButtonLookFocused,
    Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}"
/>
```

I did not test this though, maybe you can try it and tell me how it goes.

Comment: I have attached an screenshot in this query please find it and share your opinion.

Comment: Seriously, what Office is to make the the "Find Next" button visually highlighted. When you type in search box, and then hit "Enter", most likely it is the search box that is getting your "Enter" key. That means the "Find Next" button itself is not getting any focus.

Comment: Edited answer, but I did not test it. You can play around this idea if you are still lost.

Comment: Ok thank you for your quick response. I will tell you once i checked.